# How to read XML file from web activity data in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-adf

For example this is the output I get from Web activity:

```
`{
    "Response": "<?xml version = 'xyz'?>
                 <Head>
                      <Blobs>
                             <Blob>
                                  <Name>Max</Name>
                                  <location>USA</location>
                             </Blob>
                             <Blob>
                                  <Name>Robert</Name>
                                  <location>UK</location>
                             </Blob>
                             <Blob>
                                  <Name>Nick</Name>
                                  <location>USA</location>
                             </Blob>
                       </Blobs>
                  </Head>",
    "Json1": {
        "Json1_1": "value",
        "Json1_1": "value",
        "Json1_1": "value",
    },
    "Json2": "value",
    "Json3": 0,
    "Json4": {
        "json4_1": 0`your text`
    }
}`
```

I want to get all Names from XML data. So I am using set variable activity and taking the web activity output as input.

I tried using expression:
**@xpath(xml(activity('Web1').output.Response), 'string(//Name)')
This is giving me only first name of the xml but I want all the name tag values from the XML above.**
The variable I used in the set varibale activity was array type.

Can someone help me to get all the name values from the output of web activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have repro'd this in my environment.

- A sample API is taken in web activity and its XML response is as in below image.

[image]

- Then Variable V1 (**array type**) is taken and it is set using set variable activity. Value is given as
  `@xpath(xml(activity('Web1').output.Response), string('//Name/text()'))`
  [image]

**Output of Set Variable Activity:**
It has all names from XML response.
[image]